# Start job for Raise network interfaces message

Tags: startup

When I start my Ubuntu machine, a message is displayed

```
A start job is running for Raise network 
interfaces (20s /5min 3s)
```

and it waits for the time given in last brackets and after that starts normally. But what that error is about?

Answer (score 0):

I've got that error while trying to start ubuntu server on virtual box with an adapter in "internal network" mode.
After some investigations, I found that in that mode there is no default DHCP server available for the virtual machine.
So if you wait till the timeout and run:

```
ifconfig -a
```

You will probably see that you have network interface without assigned IP address.